# Is there such a thing like $Ψ(s)$ where $s$ is the state of the spin of the particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-information, quantum-spin

The wavefunction of a particle is most of the times a function of the particle's position. Is there a wavefunction as a function of the particle's spin (or both) and if yes how is it affected?

Comment: Yes, of course, your text should detail how the spin values along an axis are represented in your wavefunction.

Comment: That "s" is a discrete variable, but yet it can be seen as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
And actually it is necessary to properly describe
the state of a particle with spin, like an electron.

You already know wavefunctions dependent on position
$$\Psi(x,y,z)$$
where ($x,y,z$) is the position coordinates in space
(each from the range between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

This is not enough for an electron (which is a spin $\frac 12$ particle).
You need an additional degree of freedom for describing its spin state.
By convention $s_z$ (the $z$-component of the spin) is used.

So you have the wavefunction
$$\Psi(x,y,z,s_z)$$
where $s_z$ can have only two different values: $+\frac 12$
and $-\frac 12$.

Alternatively you can write this wavefunction also as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\Psi_{+1/2}(x,y,z) \\
\Psi_{-1/2}(x,y,z)
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\Psi_{+1/2}(x,y,z)$ and $\Psi_{-1/2}(x,y,z)$ are
two plain complex-valued functions depending on position.